# Endless progress indicator on cancel of google sign in dialog flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

When I am tapping on the blank screen to cancel the sign in. I am getting endless loading screen. I am not able to figure out how to dismiss the progress Indicator upon cancelling.

Here's code for Google sign in:

```
final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future signInGoogle() async {
try {
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();

  final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
      await googleUser?.authentication;
  final OAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
  );
  final UserCredential userCredential =
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final User? user = userCredential.user;
  return _userFromFirebase(user);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  return e.message ?? e.toString();
}
}
```

On Welcome screen I'm using bool isLoading to show progress indicator. When result == null, I'm using setState to set isLoading = false but it is not working for me. It shows loading screen endlessly. Do you know what I have to do to show welcome screen upon cancelling sign in.

Here's code for Welcome Screen:

```
bool isLoading = false;

isLoading
    ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive())
    : Scaffold(
        appBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(middle: navbarLogo()),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Spacer(),
                Center(
                  child: Text('Discover',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                ),
                Spacer(),

                ///Google Sign In Button
                SignInButton(
                    widget:
                        Image.asset('images/google-logo.png', height: 22.0),
                    title: 'Continue with Google',
                    onTap: () async {
                      try {
                        setState(() => isLoading = true);
                        final result =
                            await _database.signInGoogle().then((value) {
                          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                              HomeScreen.id,
                              ModalRoute.withName(HomeScreen.id));
                        });
                        if (result == null) {
                          setState(() => isLoading = false);
                          if (kDebugMode) {
                            print('error signing in');
                          }
                        }
                      } on Exception catch (e) {
                        if (kDebugMode) {
                          print(e);
                        }
                      }
                    }),
```

UPDATE: The thing is everything was working fine before this. Location Provider was also working fine. When I did that, It crashed suddenly with this error.

Error:

Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this FeedScreen Widget

E/flutter (11935): This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider

E/flutter (11935): of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

E/flutter (11935):

E/flutter (11935): - You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.

E/flutter (11935):   To fix, perform a hot-restart.

E/flutter (11935): - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

E/flutter (11935):   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then

E/flutter (11935):   other routes will not be able to access that provider.

E/flutter (11935): - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

E/flutter (11935):   Make sure that FeedScreen is under your MultiProvider/Provider.

E/flutter (11935):   This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

Sign out issue Edit:

This is my sign out method in Auth Screen:

```
Future signOut() async {
try {
  await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  await googleSignIn.disconnect();
  await googleSignIn.signOut();
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}
}
```

In Account Screen I'm call this signOut() method:

```
TextButton(
             onPressed: () {
               _authService.signOut();
             },
        child: Text('Sign Out'),
       ),
```

I'm wrapping my initialRoute with WrapperScreen where I'm checking If currentUser == null ? WelcomeScreen() : HomeScreen ();

But when I click on Sign out. I get Signed out but I'm not getting redirected to WelcomeScreen which I should as I'm checking that on Wrapper Screen. Do you know what I am doing wrong. I'm really grateful for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that you are always returning some value from your signInGoogle() method, so the value of result in your Welcome screen would never be null. Try this instead:
Modify your signInGoogle to return null if google sign in is not successful and also on any exception as:

```
Future signInGoogle() async {
try {
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  if(googleUser == null){
  return null;
  }
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
      await googleUser?.authentication;
  final OAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
  );
  final UserCredential userCredential =
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final User? user = userCredential.user;
  return _userFromFirebase(user);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
   return null;
  //return e.message ?? e.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and loading widget stopped but then as soon as welcome screen came it crashed my app with an error. I'm updating the answer with the error

Comment: The issue is all together different when I use the above solution. I also need to figure out how to handle the provider thingy

Comment: Wrap your MaterialApp with the provider you want to access and the issue would be gone.

Comment: I did that and the error is gone but now when I sign out. I get signed out but I'm not getting redirected to Welcome Screen. I am editing the above code with sign out use case. Please take a look.

Comment: you could listen to FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges to get notified whenever auth states changes and perform actions accordingly. But if you wish to do it manually then, you need to navigate to the login page manually after calling sign out method.So in your signOut() function, add a code for navigation to login or any other page after calling await googleSignIn.signOut();

Comment: Hey Suvash, Thank you! I sorted it out. It's working. Much appreciated!